# Java <> type returning from function

Tags: java, junit

I'm creating JUnit 4 test case on some unknown code. When I run it I get this exception message:

`java.lang.AssertionError: An icon should be an image expected null, but was:<>`

What is the <> type?

test case

```
@Test
public void testCreateAppletImageIcon_OpenExecutable_ReturnsNull() {
     ImageIcon icon = DiningPhilosophers.createAppletImageIcon("images/banner.exe", "");
     Assert.assertNull("An icon should be an image", icon);
}
```

Comment: Add the unit test case here, without that, nothing can be said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means the empty string; JUnit puts the value in angle brackets.

Comment: Is that allowed since icon is an ImageIcon? How can it be returning a String

Comment: That's the output of the icon's `toString`, which is apparently the image path.